# while running the program for trading bot, i am having the following error

Tags: python

Its a Algorithmic trading bot.
while running the program for trading bot, i am having the following error

```
File "C:\Users\SHALU\Desktop\FXBot-main\FXBot-main\main.py", line 25, in <module>
    oanda = tpqoa.tpqoa("oanda.cfg")

  File "C:\Users\SHALU\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tpqoa\tpqoa.py", line 55, in __init__
    self.access_token = self.config['oanda']['access_token']

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\configparser.py", line 963, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)

KeyError: 'oanda'
```

Comment: it's a tool. is it your tool? or someone else's tool? you/we need the code to check it out.

Comment: It looks like you have a config file `oanda.cfg` and an entry called `oanda` is missing there.